# Date format not working mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: date, datetime, vb6

I am creating a function that convert octal to decimal to date. I already do the part of convert octal to decimal to date but i cannot get the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. Here is my code:

```
Public Function OctToDate(ByVal OctDate As String) As String
  Dim LDate As Long
  Dim ODate As String
  Dim StrDate As String
  Dim PlainDate As Date

  ODate = OctDate
  LDate = CLng("&O" & ODate)
  StrDate = CDate(Format(LDate, "####/##/##"))
  PlainDate = Format(StrDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
  MsgBox (PlainDate)
End Function
```

But the result that i always get is `10/15/2017` and the result that i want is `2017-10-15` can anyone help me? im stuck

Comment: can anyone explain to me why i get downvote?

Comment: I don't know much VB6, but it looks like you're trying to reformat a *string* (`Format$(StrDate, ...)`) - that doesn't look right to me. You're also then ignoring the result of `PlainDate` anyway, printing out `StrDate` instead. Also, the format in the body of your question doesn't match the title.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry i forgot to updated my code because i tried to put `$` to try if it will work but it still it didn't work. I dont get any error so i dont have any idea what is wrong

Comment: You're still trying to format a *string* rather than a *date*. Your `StrDate` and `PlainDate` variables look like they're the wrong way round. `CDate` returns a `Date`, not a `String`, and `Format` returns a `String`, not a `Date`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried some trial and error on the code and i get what is wrong

Comment: Where does octal come in?  This whole thing looks insane, just random scratchings.

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening behind the scene, but I believe VB is seeing that this is a date, and is displaying it to the user in the system's date format. `MsgBox Format(StrDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is about data type

Before:

`Dim PlainDate As Date`

After:

`Dim PlainDate As String`

I declare `PlainDate` as date but the `Format` returns `strings` thats why it does not change the format. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer with the code sample::

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241719(v=vs.60).aspx

I hope help you.

Comment: I already tried it and it return the same result. I dont know what is the problem

Comment: @Feras to improve your answer you should reproduce the relevant portions from your link. The link may disappear someday.